# Month Start Date through DAX formula

Tags: date, powerbi, expression, dax, monthcalendar

I have dates in data from

```
02 Aug 2018 
03 Aug 2018 
04 Aug 2018
.
.
.
.
30 Aug 2018..
```

Now i want start of the month date through Dax formula which is 01/08/2018. But in data date is 02/08/2018 which i dont want

i tried below formula

```
Start_Monthdate = STARTOFMONTH(EStart_Date[Date])
```

through above formula i get 02 Aug 2018 which i dont want

Answer (score 2):

In DAX, what you can do is use the EOMONTH function.

https://dax.guide/eomonth/

Column Name = EOMONTH(table[date], -1) + 1

So the above DAX is finding the end of the previous month, then adding 1 day to it.
For the date 2/4/2020, EOMONTH gets the date 31/3/2020, then adds one day to get 1/4/2020

Answer (score 0):

Time intelligence only works reliably if you use it on a calendar table that has all the dates in the year you're working with. Since your date column is missing the first day of the month, `STARTOFMONTH` returns the first one that you do have.

Without creating a proper calendar table, you either use `EOMONTH` as @Jonee mentioned or try this:

```
DATE ( YEAR ( EStart_Date[Date] ), MONTH ( EStart_Date[Date] ), 1 )
```